# Permission error when stored procedure is executing SSIS package as 'sa'

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis, database-permissions

I have a stored procedure that execute an ssis import package, that stored procedure is called by a service broker queue.
I get the following error :

```
'The server principal "sa" is not able to access the database "SSISDB" under the current security context.'
```

- In the queue definition the activation procedure is setted "EXECUTE AS SELF"
- The SSISDB owner appeards to be by my usual login (ActiveDirectory login) (Apparently only windows logins, not database logins, can use SSIS ?)
- Tried to modify the queue definition to "EXECUTE AS " apparently sa can't impersonate another account.

Should I (and how / would that be harmless) change the SSISDB database owner to sa (well... dbo I guess ?)
Is there another way to allow sa to execute the ssis package ?

Comment: Big topic. Your issue is not with SSIS as such, but a generic cross-database security issue (assuming you're using `SSISDB.catalog.start_execution` to run the package). There's lots to say about that. [Here's more background info than you probably want or need](http://sommarskog.se/grantperm.html). The "simple" solutions here involve twiddling `TRUSTWORTHY` and cross-database ownership chaining, but those have potential security implications that should be reviewed.

Comment: I tried to follow the article but I get "Msg 15199 The current security context is non-revertible" When executing as my user which is allowed to execute ssis packages...